Property of continuous function over a compact and connected set
If $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is non-empty, compact and connected. If $f\in C(A,\mathbb{R})$ and $m\in \mathbb{N} $, choose arbitrary points $x_1,...,x_m\in A$. Show that there exists $\alpha\in A$ such that $f(\alpha)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m} f(x_j)$.

The image of a continuous function over a compact set is compact.
Since $A$ is compact, it is closed and bounded. Since $A$ is closed, the limit of any convergent sequence in $A$ is also in $A$.
But I don't know how to proceed after this. Any help is welcome

Hint:
$$
\min \Big{ f(x_1), \cdots, f(x_m) \Big}
\le
\underbrace{\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m f(x_i)}_{{\text{avg. of the $f(x_i)$'s}}}
\le
\max \Big{ f(x_1), \cdots, f(x_m) \Big}
$$

Hint 1: Focus on the case $m=2$, and use the intermediate value theorem to find a valid $\alpha$ that lies on the segment between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Hint 2: for general $m$, use induction.

And you do not need compactness.

You can prove this by the intermediate value theorem.
Intermediate value theorem: Let $X$ is a connected space, $f: \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $a,b \in f(X)$, $a < b$, then for $t \in [a,b]$ we have $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = t$.
Let $t$ be the minimum of the function $f$ in $A$, and $T$ be the maximum of the function $f$ in $A$. Since $A$ is compact $t, T \in f(A)$. Observe that
$$t \leq \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m f(x_i) \leq T.$$
Hence using the intermediate value theorem we have $\alpha \in A$ such that $$f(\alpha) = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m f(x_i).$$ You don't need the fact that $A$ is compact. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally compact, any finite number of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be bounded by a compact set.
